# Matplotlib: $$ formatting in axis label loses font

Tags: matplotlib

I am a simple bridge engineer who can do a bit of Python programming.
For the purposes of my PhD thesis, I create graphs using matplotlib.
I have a problem with the font getting lost in the axis labels if I use $$ in formatting - the part limited by dollars is in a different font than the one set (Barlow).

For example label of compressive strength of concrete:

fcm [MPa] - 'fcm' should be italic, 'cm' should be subscript, [MPa] should be normal text

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Figure dimensions:
cm = 1 / 2.54
height = 7
width = 12
dpi = 300
plt.figure(figsize=(round(width * cm, 6), round(height * cm, 6)), dpi=dpi)
ax = plt.axes()

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0625, right=0.85, top=0.9286, bottom=0.1429)

# Data:
x_list = [30, 50, 60, 80]
y_list = [24, 26, 30, 34]
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, linewidth=0, marker='o', markersize=2.5)

#Axis label:
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.set(xlim=(25, 85), ylim=(20, 38))

x_labels = [i for i in range(30, 85, 10)]
y_labels = [i for i in range(25, 38, 5)]

ax.set_xticks(x_labels)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels, font='Barlow', fontsize=8, va='center')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(bottom=False, pad=5)

ax.set_yticks(y_labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels, font='Barlow', fontsize=8, ha='right')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(bottom=False, pad=0)

ax.set_xlabel('$\it{f}_{cm}$ [MPa]', font='Barlow', size=9, ha='left', va='center')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.0256, 0)

plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', axis='both', color='#7F7F7F', linewidth=0.2, linestyle=(0, (10, 10)))

plt.show()
```

The result is that all the formatting is correct, except that 'fcm' is in a different font. My guess is that it is some sort of default font.

I tried a few different ideas that ChatGPT threw at me (e.g. raw strings), but none worked. Finally, he suggested using LaTeX, but that's way too complicated for me.

Is there an easy way to make the whole label in Barlow font?

Comment: Check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). You can use `\mathdefault{...}` to set the font to Barlow... but it will remove the italics. Don't think you can choose both default AND italics for some parts...

Answer (score 2):

Guided by Redox's hint, I found a solution:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'Barlow:italic'
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathit{f}_{cm}$ [MPa]', font='Barlow', size=9, ha='left', va='center')
```

Now everything is in Barlow, as i expected. Thank you very much Redox!

Comment: You can also set Barlow as the default font so you don't need to specify it for each title and axis label.